# form to update not updating pretty confused

Tags: php, forms, updates

Ok so I have tried a few different pieces of code to find that its not doing what I want it to and what it should do, what i have is a form that allows users to change a row they selected but when you change the text in the text boxes then click the submit button which then goes to editdata.php it doesn't change it.

any help will be greatly appreciated!

the form:

```
<table>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "x", "x") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("x") or die(mysql_error());
$order = "SELECT track_name, contents FROM track where track_id='".$_SESSION['user']['track_id']."'";
$result = mysql_query($order);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


?>
<form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
<tr>
<th>Track Name</th>
<th>Contents</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="track_name" id="track_name" value=" <? echo     ($row['track_name']); ?> "></td>
<td><input type="text" name="contents" id="contents" size="20" value=" <? echo ($row['contents']); ?> "></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<input type="submit" name="submit value" value="Edit">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

edit_data.php

```
<?php ob_start();
 mysql_connect("localhost", "x", "x") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("x") or die(mysql_error());

$track_name = $_POST['track_name'];
$contents = $_POST['contents'];

  $order = ("UPDATE track
            SET track_name = $track_name,
                contents = $contents 
            where track_id = '".$_SESSION['user']['track_id']."' ")
  or die(mysql_error());
  header("location:tracks");
?>
```

Comment: where you executing the update query? I mean mysql_query()?

Comment: I think you should execute update query to achieve your goal. And FYI mysql is already deprecated. Please use mysqli.

Comment: Sorry changed some of it I deleted the or die(mysql_error()); and put in mysql_query($order); but still didn't update :/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "x", "x","db_name");

$query = "UPDATE track
        SET track_name = '".$track_name."',
            contents = '".$contents."' 
        where track_id = ".$_SESSION['user']['track_id'];

mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

I use mysqli_query since mysql is already deprecated.

NOTE: I edit the where clause to fit if track_id is an integer. no need to put it inside quote.

Comment: you mean like mysqli_query("localhost","x","x", $query); ?

Comment: Changed mine to what you put but still it doesn't update, is their anything wrong with my form code?

Comment: Did you call session_start() before you use session?